# Procedure which modify existing trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to create procedure which modify existing trigger. Trigger is responsible for blocking rows from beeing updated with specific ID. I tried something like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Change_trigger
    @List_of_ids varchar(8000)
AS 
ALTER TRIGGER blocks
ON ttt
INSTEAD OF update 
AS
BEGIN
    If (SELECT Id_ttt FROM inserted) IN (@List_of_ids)
      BEGIN
          raiserror('You cannot modify this record.', 12, 1)
          RETURN
      END

    UPDATE ttt
    SET
    field1 = INSERTED.field1
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE INSERTED.Id_ttt = ttt.Id_ttt
END
```

Parameter `@List_of_ids` would be like this: `2,3,4,5,9,52`. But when I try to create this procedure I got error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Change_trigger, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

The trigger is created.

Comment: Rather than continually modifying a trigger, why not just have a table containing the banned IDs that the trigger then references? Then the procedure can just take care of populating this table - if the procedure is needed at all. By the way, SQL Server has built in types *designed* to deal with multiple values (table-valued parameters, XML). `varchar` isn't one of them.

Comment: Also, your trigger is broken. The `IN` operator requires a scalar value on its left. When `inserted` contains *multiple* rows (as it easily can), the trigger will generate an error. (And, of course, a single update may affect *some* rows in the block list and *some* rows that aren't. How do you want to deal with that situation? At the moment, *all* of those updates would be rejected, but is that what you *wanted* or just an accident of how you've built this trigger?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks for your comment. So how can I handle with multiple rows update in one query? To just block specific IDs when I want to keep the trigger like that? You've also meantioned about other table to store banned IDs there. It's interesting. But I need procedure because this blocking IDs will be changing

Comment: "I need procedure because this blocking IDs will be changing" - as opposed to how difficult it is to change values in a table? I.e. the thing that databases do *all of the time*?

Comment: So, I would have another table contains blocking IDs. Trigger would check before update/delete (clausule `instead of`) if updating ID is in that table, if yes - message, if not - update. And I would have a procedure/function with parameter to add or remove ID from that table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the trigger I'd write, once.

```
ALTER TRIGGER blocks
ON ttt
INSTEAD OF update 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE t
    SET
    field1 = i.field1
    FROM INSERTED i
            inner join
         ttt t
            on i.Id_ttt = t.Id_ttt
            left join
         ttt_blocked on tb
            on
               i.Id_ttt = tb.Id_ttt
    WHERE
        tb.Id_ttt is null
END
```

Note that this trigger no longer throws an error for blocked updates but it does allow for a mixed update (some rows blocked, some rows not) to occur. There's no clean way to raise an error whilst still *partially* applying an update in a trigger.

Then I'd have a table (referenced above):

```
CREATE TABLE ttt_blocked (
   Id_ttt int not null,
   constraint PK_ttt_blocked PRIMARY KEY (Id_ttt)
)
```

And then, if necessary, I'd create a procedure to maintain this *table* rather than continually changing the database schema:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Change_blocking
  @BlockedIDs xml
AS
    --Better option would be table-valued parameters
    --but I've chosen to do XML today

    --We expect the XML to be of the form
    --<blocks>
    --  <id>10</id>
    --  <id>15</id>
    --</blocks>

    MERGE INTO ttt_blocked t
    USING (select x.id.value('text()[1]','int')
           from @BlockedIDs.nodes('/blocks/id') x(id)) s(Id_ttt)
    ON
      t.Id_ttt = s.Id_ttt
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id_ttt) VALUES (s.Id_ttt)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

As I also allude to above, I'd generally recommend [Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than XML (and either of them ahead of `varchar` since they're *designed* to hold multiple values) but it would have added even more code to this answer.

Comment: Instead of creating procedure I can directly add/delete rows from that ttt_blocked table from my application right? I don't need procedure

Comment: @XardasLord - yes, that's why I was couching it in terms of "if necessary" in my answer or "if the procedure is needed at all" in the comments.

Comment: I have a question, is there any way to keep the condition like this: `If (SELECT Id_ttt FROM inserted) IN (SELECT Id_ttt FROM ttt_blocked)` and show error message when record is blocked? But I mean a query which updates few rows. Some loop through `inserted` or something?

Comment: Or with your update statement which allows for a mixed update - is there a way to show message if record is blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Change_trigger
    @List_of_ids varchar(4000)
AS 
begin
declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql ='
ALTER TRIGGER blocks
ON ttt
INSTEAD OF update 
AS
BEGIN
    if exists (SELECT Id_ttt FROM inserted where  Id_ttt IN ('+@List_of_ids+'))
      BEGIN
          raiserror(''You cannot modify this record.'', 12, 1)
          RETURN
      END

    UPDATE ttt
    SET
    field1 = INSERTED.field1
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE INSERTED.Id_ttt = ttt.Id_ttt
END' ;
exec (@sql);
END
```

Comment: Great, procedure has been created. But when I try to execute it I got this error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure change, Line 40
Incorrect syntax near the object "Id_ttt"`.. I exec with this: `EXEC Change_trigger @List_of_ids = '2,4,6'`

Comment: SELECT Id_ttt FROM inserted where Id_ttt IN (@List_of_ids).  Is this the correct correct systax?

Comment: You can't just `IF (query)`. You're probably looking for `EXISTS`. Also, the error Xardas is reporting is probably fixed just by adding the matching `END` for the `BEGIN` of the trigger.

Comment: editted the answer. i missed that.  @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks